# Got 404 error while using Flask framework

Tags: python, html, templates, flask

I was trying to run my html code using `flask` framework. When I tried to run the python script, it showed `404 error` in the browser

```
<html>
   <body>

      <h1>Hello world!</h1>

   </body>
</html>
```

**python script**:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/hello/<user>')
def hello_name(user):
   return render_template('hello.html', name = user)

if __name__ == '__main__':
   app.run(debug = True)
```

What is the reason of this error?

Answer (score 0):

The code works fine. 
Make sure that you keep the html file in `templates` folder. My folder structure is like this:

```
flask_app
├── hello.py
└── templates
    └── hello.html
```

And also visiting the `http://127.0.0.1:5000/` will cause the error as you did not define any view for root path.

While visiting the indexed path `http://127.0.0.1:5000/hello/arsho` I got the expected view:

[image: Hello world in flask]

Answer (score 0):

Use jinja to print your name

```
<html>
   <body>
      <h1>Hello {{name}}</h1>
   </body>
</html>
```

Go throught the [flask quickstart](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/quickstart/)